# Google Apps Script send attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

currently I can send pdf from google spreadsheet to email with this script with attachment, but the attachment fail to send

this is my current script :

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HELPER").hideSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var getLastRow = 4000; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 4, getLastRow, 7);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var trigger = row[0];
    var emailAddress = row[2]; // Email column
    if(emailAddress != "" && emailAddress != " "){ 
      var message = "Hi,\n\nSilahkan download dan print attachment ini.\n\nTerima Kasih,\nSistemHBR"; // Content column
      var subject = "FORM CUTI";
      var status_email = row[6];
      if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')); // Prevents sending duplicates
      attachments = [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("FORM CUTI")]; { 
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
        // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HELPER").activate();
        
  }
  //MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HELPER").activate();
   }
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code above?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, I thought that when `if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT'))` is `true`, you might have wanted to send the email. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')); // Prevents sending duplicates
 attachments = [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("FORM CUTI")]; { 
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
   // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HELPER").activate();

}
```

#### To:

```js
if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')) {
  attachments = [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("FORM CUTI")];
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: attachments});
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HELPER").activate();
}
```

- In this case, when `(trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')` is `true`, an email is sent by including the attachment file.

#### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for advance

I tried your script, it was work...the pdf sent successfully but it keep sent the duplicates which has status 'EMAIL_SENT' on it

Comment: Oh I forgot to change trigger TRUE to FALSE after email sent

Comment: @IndraAzenx `the pdf sent successfully but it keep sent the duplicates which has status 'EMAIL_SENT' on it` In this case, I think the column you are getting for `status_email` is 10 (since the first column in your range is 4), and the one where you are writing `EMAIL_SENT` is 7. This discrepancy might explain why you are getting duplicates.

Comment: Oh yes my bad, it work right now...Thank you